# long running selenium test - Browser dies

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a selenium test that performs a repeated set of actions on an application, to test exactly what happens when the same thing is done many many times. This is done with an infinite loop, because I don't actually need a pass/fail, I just need to see if it's still there in 2/4/8/24/48 hours. The problem I'm having is that something causes my browser to die during the night.

```
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:493)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:244)
[junit]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:77)
[junit]     at wl12cStartServers.<method1>(<testname>.java:66)
[junit]     at wl12cStartServers.<method2>(<testname>.java:34)
[junit] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

This is the same error as would appear if i were to kill the browser window started by selenium, But I have no idea what is causing it to die in this instance..
I have seen the script run for several hours when I'm watching it..

Comment: It might sound basic but your computer doesn't go into sleep mode during the night or anything does it?

Comment: I get something similar as well, it's honestly like as soon as you look away selenium falls over.

Comment: I realised that this is also happening to me. Browser just dies. Sometime, somewhere, hard to reproduce. Only workaround is just to check constantly if browser is still there and if not, relaunch it...

Comment: Does this happen with any browser, are are you lot using the same one?

Comment: I have only attempted this with firefox. My machine does not sleep at night, but it was something worth checking!

Answer (score 0):

As user KPZ suggested, the problem might be in computer going to sleep mode (or anything similar) during the test. Try this countermeasure:

```
private static Timer screenSaverDisabler;

/** Moves mouse once in a minute and therefore prevents the screen saver from kicking in. */
private static void disableScreenSaver() {
    screenSaverDisabler = new Timer();
    screenSaverDisabler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        Robot r = null;
        // initialization block
        {
            try {
                r = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException headlessEnvironmentException) {
                screenSaverDisabler.cancel();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Point loc = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            r.mouseMove(loc.x + 1, loc.y);
            r.mouseMove(loc.x, loc.y);
        }
    }, 0, 59*1000);
}
```

Also, try not to forget to call `screenSaverDisabler.cancel();` when you're done.

---

If this didn't help, I don't know what's causing the problem. In case you won't find out, there's the obvious solution:

It's a recoverable exception! Add a `try-catch` block in your main loop that will catch this problem (catch any `RemoteWebdriverException` and filter out those that aren't caused by `SocketTimeoutException`) and restart the browser.

Comment: Good idea, But what happens in the case where my application dies? I assume I will fail with a timeout error?

Comment: @confusified I'm not sure I understand correctly. Do you need a single browser instance in order to test the application? That means that once the browser dies, you can't continue testing at the point you ended? Oh, in that case, we need to find the reason for the browser crash, indeed.

Comment: Scenario 1 - Browser dies for unknown reason, This means My application will still be standing. My test will have ended before uncovering any problems. If the browser died on iteration 5, and I restart the test it will start again from iteration 1, which will fail because iteration 1 has not been cleaned up from the previous run. does that make any sense?

Scenario 2 - Application dies. In this case a bug will likely have caused the error, and selenium will end either due to an assertion, or in the worst case, because of a timeout error on searching for some element, as anticipated.

Comment: @confusified Scenario 1 is clear to me and you are right that simply restarting the browser is not really an option, sadly. So my solution is not really viable. I'll delete the answer. Scenario 2 is okay, the problem would propagate well and the test would fail as needed.

Comment: I would leave the answer, As it's still helpful to someone who's not in my exact scenario :)